# The command '/bin/sh -c service mongod start' return a non-zero code: 1 in docker

Tags: mongodb, docker

i'm trying to create a docker image run Mongodb on my Raspberry Pi 3+ with Raspbian buster. But when i build image and run container, mongodb doesn't auto start, so i add command `RUN service mongod start` then build image. Mongodb seems to be installed, i checked by `service --status-all` and mongodb listed but not started. Error come when docker try to start mongodb serive: `The command '/bin/sh -c service mongod start' return a non-zero code: 1`.

This is myDockerfile:

```
FROM cretzel/rpi-mongodb
WORKDIR /usr/src/mongodb

RUN chmod +x /var/lib/mongodb
RUN service mongod start

EXPOSE 27017

CMD ["mongod"]
```

I tried to fix this and be told that it doesn't have permission, so i add `RUN chmod +x /var/lib/mongodb` to my dockerfile but it don't work.

Can someone help?

---------------- Update from @Adiii's answer -----------------------------------
My new dockerfile:

```
FROM cretzel/rpi-mongodb
WORKDIR /usr/src/mongodb
COPY ./entrypoint.sh .
RUN chmod +x ./entrypoint.sh
VOLUME ./database /data/db
EXPOSE 27017
CMD ["mongod"]
```

entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
service mongod start
exec "$@"
```

The change solved  my error but mongodb service still cannot start. This is log file:

```
Starting database: mongodb failed!
db level locking enabled: 1
mongod --help for help and startup options
Mon Nov 11 16:31:15 
Mon Nov 11 16:31:15 warning: 32-bit servers don't have journaling enabled by default. Please use --journal if you want durability.
Mon Nov 11 16:31:15 
warning: some regex utf8 things will not work.  pcre build doesn't have --enable-unicode-properties
Mon Nov 11 16:31:15 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db/ 32-bit host=38271f34412b
Mon Nov 11 16:31:15 [initandlisten] 
Mon Nov 11 16:31:15 [initandlisten] ** NOTE: This is a development version (2.1.1-pre-) of MongoDB.
Mon Nov 11 16:31:15 [initandlisten] **       Not recommended for production.
Mon Nov 11 16:31:15 [initandlisten] 
Mon Nov 11 16:31:15 [initandlisten] ** NOTE: when using MongoDB 32 bit, you are limited to about 2 gigabytes of data
Mon Nov 11 16:31:15 [initandlisten] **       see http://blog.mongodb.org/post/137788967/32-bit-limitations
Mon Nov 11 16:31:15 [initandlisten] **       with --journal, the limit is lower
Mon Nov 11 16:31:15 [initandlisten] 
Mon Nov 11 16:31:15 [initandlisten] db version v2.1.1-pre-, pdfile version 4.5
Mon Nov 11 16:31:15 [initandlisten] git version: 47fbbdceb21fc2b791d22db7f01792500647daa9
Mon Nov 11 16:31:15 [initandlisten] build info: Linux raspberrypi 3.2.27+ #102 PREEMPT Sat Sep 1 01:00:50 BST 2012 armv6l BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
Mon Nov 11 16:31:15 [initandlisten] options: {}
Mon Nov 11 16:31:15 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
Mon Nov 11 16:31:15 [websvr] admin web console waiting for connections on port 28017
Mon Nov 11 16:32:15 [clientcursormon] mem (MB) res:20 virt:83 mapped:0
```

I don't understand Docker so much, it don't show any error. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not start the process at `RUN` command, each run command run at a separate shell and `RUN` is for installation and configuration not to start the process. To start the process in the container you need to start the process at `entrypoint` or `CMD`.

also, the container needs a process to run in foreground so service will not work in case of the container. so

```
EXPOSE 27017
CMD ["mongod"]
```

This is enough to start the mongo process, if the container is up and running it's mean mongod process is running, you do not need to check the status using `service --status-all`. as soon as MongoDB process dies container will die automatically.

Will suggest to use [offical mongo docker image.](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo)

Comment: Thanks for answer. I've add entrypoint.sh and it seem work. But another error show up.Caused error quite long so i updated on the question.

Comment: I'm using raspbian buster so offical mongo isn't fit with 32bit OS.